# How to embed copies of static library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, linker

Here is structure of my solution:

[image]

`A.lib` defines:

```
int a(void) { return 1; }
```

`B.lib` defines:

```
int b(void) { return a(); }
```

`C.lib` defines:

```
int c(void) { return a() * 2; }
```

`SharedStaticLibsTest.exe` defines:

```
int main(void) { std::cout << b() + c() << std::endl; return 0;}
```

I decided to check (via `DumpBin`) code embeded to result application. It turns out that `B` and `C` libraries use the only instance of `A` library. Is there any way (for educational purposes) to use two different instances of `A` inside `B` and `C`? Maybe there is specific option of linker for this stuff? I understand, that such behavior may have unexpected side effects, which depend on logic of `A` library.

P.S. I replaced references to project by direct including .lib file within properties of project. Now `B`, `C` projects have a copy of `A` project. But final project still has the only copy of `A` library. I have no idea how does linker solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean library instance? Duplicate the library code?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, yes.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, just for educational purposes. I understand that it is not good practise.

Comment: do both instances need to be exactly the same? maybe it might be possible to build them with different settings/version and specify which dependent library use with version?

Comment: @slawekwin, it is not important (libraries can be the same, can be compiled with different settings). I am just curious about resolving such issue. I don't understand whether it is possible or not. How does linker resolve presence of multiple symbols with the same name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you ever end up with two instances of `A` in the build, all exported identifiers from `A` need to follow the [One-Definition-Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

That is, even if you can technically have two different versions of `A`, unless they are for all intents and purposes identical, your program is invalid and neither the compiler nor the linker is obliged to tell you (the C++ standard calls this *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*). In practice this means you will have *very* weird bugs in your program and no clue where they come from.

That being said, technically there's nothing that stops you from constructing situations like the one you ask for. Normally static dependencies are only being processed at the linking stage. So a static library `B` depending on another static library `A` will not cause the one to export symbols from the other - `B` will not contain any symbols from `A`.

Instead your build system will track that dependency and as soon as you arrive at a linker stage (eg. by building an executable that depends on `B`), the build system will take care that *both* libraries get linked. That also means that if you don't have a build system, or configure your build incorrectly, you will get a linker errors for missing the symbols from the `A` library, even though you link against `B` and `C` explicitly.

So the canonical, portable way of duplicating symbols requires pulling them in through *dynamic libraries*, because those pass through the linker. If you change `B` and `C` to be dynamic libraries, they will both link against `A` and contain their own separate versions of the used functions from `A`. If you changed `A` between building `B` and `C`, they will contain different definitions. Hopefully your build system will try to prevent that from happening.
Note that the C++ standard does not have a whole lot to say about dynamic libraries, so for the technicalities of how symbols get resolved here and what the effect of duplicated symbols is going to be, refer to your operating system's manual.

With MSVC, there is the additional possibility to do this for static libraries as well. In the project properties for `B` or `C`, head to *Librarian* -> *General* and set the *Link Library Dependencies* option to `Yes`. Now if you rebuild and look at the dumps for the `B.lib` and `C.lib` again, they should contain the symbols from `A` as well. Of course when building the resulting executable, the linker will pick either the version from `B` or from `C` (or also from `A` directly, depending on how you're linking) for each of `A`'s symbols that is being used. Please don't do this in production.

Comment: Thanks, I thought in similar way. The only "tricky" case  - How does linker choose some version of symbol (If duplicated symbols occur)?

Comment: @LmTinyToon It usually just takes the first one it encounters. But an implementation is free to do whatever, as the standard requires all available definitions to be equivalent.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: shouldn't the linker complain about symbol's having been defined multiple times, if following the example in the last paragraph of your answer?

Comment: @tangoal As the answer mentions, the linker is not required to tell you. If it can diagnose the error and tells you about it, fine (and in some cases this is indeed what happens), but you have no guarantee from the language that this will happen. This is due to how the C linker model works, which indeed makes it impossible to diagnose these errors in many cases.